# How do I use cache in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I want to use [cache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/213/Cache) in [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/). How do I use it?

Comment: When I first saw this, I misread the title as "How do you use cake in cakephp" :)

Comment: best advice when asking a general question like this is to read the docs first, after that if you still have problems understanding, state what you didn't understand or a code sample of your app that's not behaving as expected, otherwise you'll just get links to the the manual.

Answer (score 6):

```
if(!($cachedPosts = Cache::read('cached_posts'))) {
    $cachedPosts = $this->Post->find('all');
    Cache::write('cached_posts', $cachedPosts);
}
```

In this code example you look if you have the data cached - if not, retrieve it from the database, and write it to the cache. On the next request, the data will come from the cache, not from the database.

Answer (score 3):

In the Cache documentation of the manual (1.2):
http://book.cakephp.org/view/213/Cache

I would recommend that you disable caching while doing development; you'll find (hopefully not the hard way, like me) that your models and views are not changing as expected.

Comment: Should note that if you must/want to use caching during development, you can manual clear the cache from your controller: Cache::clear()
(see "7.2.6 Clearing the Cache" in the manual).

Answer (score 2):

Read the Documentation:

- http://book.cakephp.org/view/213/Cache
- http://book.cakephp.org/view/325/View-Caching
- http://book.cakephp.org/search/cache

Answer (score 2):

Before  using the cache we have to check that cache is enabled or disabaled  in

***app/config/core.php.***

we have to uncomment this line in core.php

```
//Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);
```

After that we use

```
$varible = Cache::read('variable');
Cache::write('posts', $posts);
Cache::delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the /app/config/core.php file.

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP provides by default file based caching at model level also...

then also to maintain manual caching for any application you can use

```
Cache::set(array('duration' => '+100 days'));
Cache::write(file_path);
```

type functions to maintain file based cache

For memcache or any other concept you can take the following links as reference:

- http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/Molot/2010/01/08/simple-way-to-memcache-almost-all-database-queries
- http://andy-gale.com/cakephp-view-memcache.html