# How to create a live blogging platform in PHP which handles 1000 of users at a time?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, cakephp

I am working on live blogging platform which must be implemented using CakePhp or Php.
It must handle 1000 of users at a time.

I've done this by auto refreshing the content using ajax when a new data is inserted in mysql table. The problem is that it hits the DB every 10 seconds to check whether the data is inserted in the past 60 seconds. If the count results 1 then I programmed to refresh the content.But it doesn't feel like an optimised solution.

Is there any way to implement this?

My code - ajax call to livefeed controller :

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
  function()
  { 
    $.post('/blog/posts/liveFeed', function(data) {
    if(data >0){
      alert(data);
      $('#content').load(window.location.href);
    }
  });
  return false;
}, 10000);
```

Livefeed controller in posts.php:

```
public function liveFeed() {
  $res=$this->Post->query('SELECT count(*) AS data FROM posts where TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), created)) < 60');
  echo $res[0][0]['data'];
}
```

I'm not good at cakePhp. So forgive me If my code looks unprofessional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some caching.

Use an http-cache like [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) and reset it every time a new article gets written - Otherwise just deliver the html page from varnish. That should give you a considerable boost in speed and possible users.

You can still reload the page every 10 seconds with an ajax request - It would just load the cached page and not query the database every time.

Comment: Varnish is indeed really fast. It can handle thousands of requests per second on common hardware.

Comment: Is there any way to reload the page only when new record is inserted in mysql table?

Comment: Not really. You'd have to push a message to the client, and normal architecture does not support push messages that easy.

But with varnish that really isn't a problem, as you only deliver a cached html page which is actually insanely fast. Just delete the cached page every time there is a new record, so the page will be generated once in cache, and then delivered again from that cache.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I will implement some cache logic between the database and the webapp. Otherwise you will have some memory troubles when too much users will be logged in and will query at the same time a lot of blogs posts.

Look this [post of stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1058006/390462) and the [Official documentation of CakePHP, v2.0, Cache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html)

It is done inside the file `app/Config/bootstrap.php` of CakePHP:

```
<?php
Cache::config('short', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 hours',
    'path' => CACHE,
    'prefix' => 'cake_short_'
));

// long
Cache::config('long', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 week',
    'probability' => 100,
    'path' => CACHE . 'long' . DS,
));
```

You have several options listed : FileCache, [ApcCache](http://php.net/apc), [Wincache](http://php.net/wincache), [XcacheEngine](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/), [MemcacheEngine](http://php.net/memcache), [RedisEngine](https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis). And of course any cache library you could have experimented because cakePHP is enough flexible to integrate it.

Comment: Is there any way to reload the page only when new record is inserted in mysql table?

Comment: Why not trigger a programmatic update of your cache if a new record is inserted inside mysql... Something like if the cacheKey is found, load cache, otherwise query database and cache the builded http response (or html partial result you will load with your ajax requests).